Sequences in vectors
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){     
    int N, valores[10000], i, j, pontuacao=0;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (i=0; i<N; i++){
        scanf("%d", &valores[i]);
    }

    for(i=0; i<N; i++){
        for(j=i+1; j<N; j++){
            if (valores[i] == valores[j])
                pontuacao++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", pontuacao);

    return 0;
}

It's supposed to be returning the number of points in a sequence of consecutive numbers, example:

input: 11 (N) 30 30 30 40 40 40 40 40 30 30 30
output: 25 (supposed to be 5)

The strange thing is that it works for other sequences.

Your code is counting duplicates, all duplicates, and multiple times. You need to check if a value is different from the previous value (where a sequence is broken), and keep track of the longest sequence through another variable. The problem would be very easy to see if you used a [debugger] to step through the code line by line.

What if one of those scanf()s fail? What if N is given a value greater than 10000?

Why is the output supposed to be 5?  I can come up with 8 or 4 using different rules but looking at adjacent entries in the array.  If you're only looking at adjacent entries, you don't need nested loops.

What does "the number of points in a sequence of consecutive numbers" mean?

You are counting the number of pairs of indexes with identical values -- which is 25 for your example.

The algorithm is fundamentally flawed in at least four ways.

The inner loop is iterating one time to few. Example, enter only one number:
1 10

Since, j = i + 1 is 1, j < 1 will be false and the loop will not do any iterations, so this sequence returns 0.
The inner loop should really be just one loop, checking if the previous element is the same as the current element.
Your algorithm counts every time the previous number equals the current number, which means that the sequence 6 10 10 20 20 30 30 counts as 3, 10 == 10, 20 == 20 and 30 == 30, while the longest sequence is 2.
If the user wants to enter more than 10000 numbers, you will write values to valores out of bounds with undefined behavior as a result.

A fix of your current code could look like this:
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_VALUES (10000)

int main() {
    int N, valores[MAX_VALUES];

    // check that scanf succeeds and that N is within bounds:
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N < 0 || N > MAX_VALUES) return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &valores[i]) != 1) return 1;
    }

    int maxlen = N > 0;  // 1 if N is greater than 0, 0 otherwise
    int pontuacao = maxlen;

    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {  // start at second element
        // ...and compare with the previous element:
        if (valores[i - 1] == valores[i]) {
            pontuacao++;
        } else {
            // a sequence ended and a new started
            if (pontuacao > maxlen) maxlen = pontuacao;
            pontuacao = 1;  // reset counter
        }
    }
    if (pontuacao > maxlen) maxlen = pontuacao;  // for the last sequence
    printf("%d\n", maxlen);
}


Since you only need to return the count of the longest sequence, you don't need to create valores[10000] and store the values in that. Keep a running counter instead. A slight rewrite of your code and it could look like this:

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int N;

    // check that scanf succeeds and that N is not less than zero
    // (no upper bound check needed)
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1 || N < 0) return 1;    
        
    int maxlen = N > 0; // 1 if N is greater than 0, 0 otherwise

    if (maxlen) {
        int pontuacao = maxlen; // or "= 1", same thing
        
        int value; // read the first value:
        if (scanf("%d", &value) != 1) return 1;

        while (--N) { // read the rest of the values
            int new_value;
            if (scanf("%d", &new_value) != 1) return 1;
            // ... and compare with the previous value:
            if (new_value == value) {
                ++pontuacao;
            } else {
                // a sequence ended and a new started
                if (pontuacao > maxlen) maxlen = pontuacao;
                value = new_value;
                pontuacao = 1; // reset counter
            }
        }
        if (pontuacao > maxlen) maxlen = pontuacao; // for the last sequence
    }  
    printf("%d\n", maxlen);
}


I'm not sure what do you want to calculate
by 'It's supposed to be returning the
number of points in a sequence of
consecutive numbers'. But according to the
test case I guess you want to calculate
the length of the longest consecutive
sequence.
The problem doesn't lie in the programming
details, but lie in the abstract algorithm.
By some tune I think this works as what
you expected:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{       
    int N, valores[10000], i, j, pontuacao=0;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        scanf("%d", &valores[i]);

    int max_seq_len_so_far = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        pontuacao = 1;
        for(j = i+1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (valores[i] != valores[j])
                break;
            pontuacao++;
        }
        if (pontuacao > max_seq_len_so_far)
            max_seq_len_so_far = pontuacao;
    }
    printf("%d", max_seq_len_so_far);
    return 0;
}

With the provided test case
11 30 30 30 40 40 40 40 40 30 30 30
it successfully prints out 5.
However, as you mentioned:

The strange thing is that it works for other sequences.

This is weird. Maybe I didn't understand
what you want to achieve in the code.
But I think it should not work in other
sequences. What are the sequences that work?
A test script, with two extra sets of test cases,
where pontuacao is the name of the
compiled executable file:
echo 11 30 30 30 40 40 40 40 40 30 30 30 | pontuacao
echo 1 1 | pontuacao
echo 7 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 | pontuacao

The second test case 1 1 should gives out 1.
The third test case 7 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 should gives out 4.
